# How to use \edef to wrap an existing macro with @inmatherr?

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a handful of existing macros that I want to wrap in some custom processing. Here's an example of the kind of thing I'm aiming to do:

```
\makeatletter
\let\olddag\textdagger
\renewcommand\textdagger{\@inmatherr\textdagger \olddag}
\makeatother
```

Then if were to try to use `$\textdagger$`, I'd get a error, rather than the existing behavior of typesetting nothing appropriate. However, `\textdagger` in regular text mode will fall through to its existing definition.

My question is, how can I achieve the same effect but without making the assignment to the intermediate command `\olddag`? I suspect there would be some voodoo using `\edef` and/or `\expandafter` that would enable me to expand:

```
{\@inmatherr\textdagger \textdagger}
```

or perhaps:

```
{\noexpand\@inmatherr\noexpand\textdagger \textdagger}
```

at definition time, so that when I invoke `\textdagger` in the body of my document, I don't get a TeX stack overflow. But I haven't yet been able to find what it is.

These other questions (and answers) may be relevant:

- [A: How do I reuse a command name two or more times?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102383/3627)
- [How to use \noexpand in an \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62223)
- [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451)
- [What is the difference between \let and \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8163)
- [How to control whether and when a macro gets expanded during another definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29021)
- [Problem with nested \noexpand and \edef](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39195)

But I haven't yet been able to piece together a solution from them. I guess it's no news that LaTeX's order-of-evaluation rules aren't that transparent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\expandafter
\renewcommand
\expandafter\textdagger
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\@inmatherr
\expandafter\textdagger
\textdagger}

\makeatoher

\begin{document}

\textdagger $\textdagger$

\end{document}
```

The above shows the general technique but in this case you already get a warning, `\textdagger` by default makes

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textdagger invalid in math mode on input line 8.
```

so an alternative would be to redefine that warning command to be an error.

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was looking for. And yes, I just cared about the general technique, not this particular case. But in fact my regular workflow (Markdown source -- Pandoc --> pdflatex --> output) doesn't show me the warnings.

Comment: @dubiousjim add `grep -i warning *.log` to the end of that pipeline :-)

Comment: Two questions: (i) Can you explain what the third `\expandafter` (the one just before the `{`) is doing? I don't understand why it is needed. (Is the `{` parsed as just another token, like `\renewcommand`? so we have to skip over it too?) (ii) Is there some translation of this solution using `\edef` instead? If there is, that would help me understand better how `\edef` and `\expandafter` stand to each other.

Comment: @dubiousjim yes `{` is just a token at that point, it's not so easy to use `\edef` as `\edef` fully expands things (and breaks any fragile command) but you just want to expand `\textdagger` _once_.

Comment: I noticed that this technique will not work with some commands, such as `\bullet`. I guess because it's not expandable? What I did in those cases was to say `texdef -tlatex bullet` on my command line and get the expansion, and then just manually include that into any `\renewcommand...`

Comment: @dubiousjim yes, bullet isn't expandable.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior of `\textdagger` is shared by all commands that are defined with `\OMS-cmd`, so a way to get errors when they're used in math mode is to change `\@inmathwarn` in the definition of `\OMS-cmd` with `\@inmatherr`. See [Why does \textbackslash render as "n" in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179126/why-does-textbackslash-render-as-n-in-math-mode) for more information about the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname OMS-cmd\endcsname{\@inmathwarn}{\@inmatherr}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\textdagger$
\end{document}
```

This gives

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textdagger invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 $\textdagger
                $
```

Comment: The easy solution I'm using now is just `\makeatletter\let\@inmathwarn\@inmatherr\makeatother`. But I did want to understand better how to use `\expandafter` properly, anyway.